# How to create file inside views folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create `php` file using `codeigniter`, I want to create that file inside views folder or inside controller/ model dynamically. But I am getting error `Message: fopen(application/views): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Looks like kind of restriction from `codeigniter`. How can I achieve this task ?

**My Code:**

```
        $file_location = APPPATH . "views"; 

        $myfile = fopen($file_location, "newfile.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "<?php\n ";  
        $txt .= "echo 'something';\n" ;
        $txt .= "?>\n ";

        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is a PHP issue I believe, not a code igniter.
See this line here:
`fopen($file_location, "newfile.php", "w")`

From the docs:
`resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = FALSE [, resource $context ]] )`

So change your fopen too:
`fopen($file_location. "newfile.php", "w")`
(I changed the , to a . to construct the file path)

Edit: make sure your `$file_location` ends with a `/` or add one to the start of `newfile.php`